# Package explorer empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I quitted Android Studio, and when coming back to my project the package explorer was empty and I the Studio didn't showed my project:
[image]

My files exists in the folder i'm using as a project so they are supposed to be showed..

I've changed the package name before, can it be related somehow? any other ideas ?

Comment: Can you try re-import the project.

Comment: Are the files shown in "Project-View"? Have you tried a full Project-Sync "Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files"?

Comment: @SailorChibi I couldn't find it in the Mac version

Comment: @BhavdipPathar That actually worked... super weird I wonder what made it happen. Write it as an answer so I could accept it

Comment: Reimporting a project does the same as syncing all the Gradle-Files again :). I see "tools" at the top of you screenshot, isn't there a submenu "Android" when you click on it?

Comment: @SailorChibi nope there isn't :)

Comment: I updated my anwser, the gradle-icon with the blue error does the same.
Four Icons left from the blue arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make this officially answered.

I don't know why but this sometimes happens with android-studio.
I noticed that a sync is needed when you use Git and check out branches which are far "apart", so many files in the working directory change.

`Reimporting` the Project or going to `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files` fixes this "issue".

`EDIT`
As @Asaf Nevo wrote there seems to be no "Android" Menu in "Tools" on Mac.
The little Gradle-Icon with the blue arrow does the same.
This Icon can be seen on the very top of the screenshot; It is the fith from right. Four Icons left from the blue questionmark.